# Angular routing: How to access parent route param in child canLoad

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-router-guards

Here's what I have for routes:

```
  {
    path: ':class_id',
    component: Class_Root_Component,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'members',
        canLoad: [ Class_Members_Can_Load ],
        loadChildren: () => import('../../class-members/class-members.module')
          .then((m) => m.Class_Members_Module)
      }
    ],
  },
```

I need to access the `:class_id` param in the `canLoad` guard to run a check.

How do I access `:class_id` within the child route `canLoad` guard?

The `canLoad` function params `route: Route` and `segments: UrlSegment[]` do not contain it as a param.

Comment: So you want to access :class_id inside  Class_Members_Can_Load ? @skwny

Comment: @GaurangDhorda yessir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232966/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-skwny).

Comment: here is your solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w4uejr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fclass-members-can-load.guard.ts @skwny